# error: ‘Default’ is not a member of ‘ns3::YansWifiPhyHelper’

Tags: apt, package-management, c, wifi-direct

I want to compile file "third.cc" on ns3.33 simulator and I have that error:
[image]
**error: ‘Default’ is not a member of ‘ns3::YansWifiPhyHelper’
108 |   YansWifiPhyHelper phy = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default ();
|                                              ^~~~~~~
Build failed
-> task in 'third' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)**

How I can solve this ?

I have used ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and python3 package **ns3.33 simulator**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you figured it out yet, but If you look on the wiki for this version, the function seems to be gone. But if you look at the source code of the previous version ns-3.32 the function is still there and is defined as:

```
 YansWifiPhyHelper
 YansWifiPhyHelper::Default (void) 
 { 
   YansWifiPhyHelper helper;
   helper.SetErrorRateModel ("ns3::NistErrorRateModel");
   return helper;
 }
```

I had some of my own code that used this function so I just replaced it like so:

```
 YansWifiPhyHelper phy;
 phy.SetErrorRateModel ("ns3::NistErrorRateModel");
```

And it worked.